# long format linear regression performed over each unique two column pairing in r (when duplicates exist in another column). Determine when response=0

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, lm, melt

have a df in quasi-long format:

```
df <- data.frame(X= c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2),
                 Y= c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2),
                 variable = c("A","A","B","B","A","A","B","B"),
                 value = c(.5,.6,1000,1000,.7,.8,2000,2000))
```

the goal is, for each unique X,Y pairing (there are 2) , 1.) perform an lm with variable A (its associated value) serving as the response variable and variable B serving as the predictor variable (its associated value), then 2.) determine (bind if possible) the predictor variable value that generates a response value of 0.

I have converted the variable column to factor and then tried pivot_wider, pivot_longer, dcast, etc. to no avail obviously because the variable has duplicate names (factor levels if converting to factor). Without further pivoting, it is likely possible to run the lm's and to determine the 0 point, then bind it to the original df for each unique X,Y pairing.

this is an example of the desired output with the final column to be populated:

```
desired <-  data.frame(X= c(1,2),
                   Y= c(1,2),
                   pred_value_B_when_response_A_equals_0 = c(NA,NA))
```

per request, here is the original wide format

```
df_wide <- data.frame(X=c(1,2),
                      Y=c(1,2),
                      A=c(.5,.6),
                      B=c(1000,1000),
                      A1=c(.7,.8),
                      B1=c(2000,2000))
```

and then I performed

```
df <- reshape2::melt(df_wide,
                      id.vars = c("X","Y"))
```

Comment: Give one example for the pair `1,1`

Comment: I don't understand. *"for each unique X,Y pairing (there are 4)"*... do you mean #1 X = 1, Y = 1; #2 X = 2, Y = 2; ... etc.? And then *"perform an lm with variable 1 (its associated value) serving as the response"* what is "variable 1" in this case? What is the predictor "variable 2"? Can you walk us through an example for the first X,Y pairing?

Comment: yes was in the process of editing this. yes it is X=1,Y=1,X=2,Y=2, etc. the variable strings used to be A,A,B,B,A1,A1,B1,B1 characters however I used gsub to remove the numeric portion of the string as they are all the same. Was in wide format originally and I melted.

Comment: and in response to the first comment a crude example of the lm is #lm_XY_11 <- lm(df, A which is comprised of c(.5,.7) ~ B c(1000,2000))
#lm_XY_22 <- lm(df, A which is comprised of c(.6,.8) ~ B c(1000,2000))

Comment: could you post the unmelted version of the data. Seems that you metled it incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

Using the wide data, rearange it to look as shown below:

```
new_dat <- df_wide %>%
  rename_with(~str_replace(.x,'(A|B)$', '\\10')) %>%
  pivot_longer(A0:B1, names_to = c('.value', 'grp'),
               names_pattern = '(.)(.)')

     X     Y grp       A     B
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1 0       0.5  1000
2     1     1 1       0.7  2000
3     2     2 0       0.6  1000
4     2     2 1       0.8  2000
```

Now in the data above, you can easily groupby X and Y and run linear model of A against B:

```
new_dat %>% 
  summarise(model=list(lm(A~B)), .by = c(X,Y))

# A tibble: 2 × 3
      X     Y model 
  <dbl> <dbl> <list>
1     1     1 <lm>  
2     2     2 <lm>
```

You can now use the linear models per group fitted to do predictions, etc

Comment: this looks promising, however, can you adapt the rename with portion of the code in the case where you have strings titled A, B, A_1, B_1, A_1_2, B_1_2? essentially I used gsub("\\_.*","", x = names(df_wide)) to remove all characters with underscore and after and then sequencing after isn't the easiest.

Comment: @user11057680 You should not remove the characters. Use them for pivoting. You need to end up with two columns. ie column A and column B. Do groupby and run lm on a against b

Comment: I used paste and rep after gsub to remove anything underscore and add a sequence suffix after so now column names appear: beep0, blah0, beep1,blah1,beep2,blah2,beep,blah4,....,beep27,blah27. then I perform your pivot_longer portion (beep0:blah27...) and it creates two groups but the beep and blah aren't split out, they remain in one shared column. guessing it is the names_pattern part. might be trouble if the columns both start with b for instance.

Comment: for others interested, one can use sapply to perform row-wise prediction of A when B ='s a given value (0 in this test case). I am sure there is a more convenient way to wrap this all in the pipe though it was not provided earlier. pred_df <- data.frame(B = 0)
lm_predict <- function(m) predict(m,pred_df)
new_dat$lm_pred_0 <- sapply(new_dat$model,lm_predict)

Answer (score 0):

```
new_dat <- pivot_longer(df_wide,cols = -c(X,Y), 
                                  names_to = c('.value', 'grp'), 
                                  names_pattern = '([a-zA-Z]+)(\\d+)')
```

solves the issue.